# Delete #NULL! in blank cells

Tags: excel, spss, cells

While exporting an SPSS (.sav) data file to excel, the blank cells were imputed as #NULL! .Is there any way to overcome this?
Even, we can replace the #NULL! by find and replace in Excel, but i need to do this in SPSS end itself.

Please assist.

Regards
Satheeshkumar

Comment: How do you export it?

Comment: He probably saves as csv. or excel file. If the variable is a string, it will output with non #NULL!, but when it is a numeric value, and the cell is empty, the excel shows the #NULL! character.Try to replace all variables to strings in spss.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider saving a copy of your original spss file, and use the syntax command of changing the variables into strings... use `alter type` command. more details here: http://www.spss-tutorials.com/changing-variable-properties-3-type/

As i wrote, you probably save your file as csv. or excel file. If the variable is a string, it will output with non #NULL!, but when it is a numeric value, and the cell is empty, the excel shows the #NULL! character.

Comment: No, if we export the data to csv format, then we won't be getting the #NULL! values for blank cells. But want i need is, to save the data as excel format.Else, we can export the data to csv and again to excel.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude #NULL, we can export by .csv file, then save as by excel file.

It works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use crtl+H to look for #Null! and replace it with nothing.